# Android - layout-large folder is been ignored

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have different layout files for
 different screens size like

Folder Structure:

- layout
- layout-large
- layout-small

  For emulators like HVGA and QVGA there
  is no problem, the respective
  layout.xml file being refereed. But
  the layout-large folder is ignored
  when I run the emulator of
  WVGA(480x854) , here it is referring
  the "layout" folder of the
  application. Please point me to the
  right direction which is right way to
  handle this situation.

  I tried using

> layout-large-hdpi  layout-large-mdpi layout-large-ldpi 
>   layout-normal-hdpi layout-normal-mdpi  layout-normal-ldpi

And in the AndroidManifest.xml I
 specified

```
   <supports-screens
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:smallScreens="true"
   android:anyDensity="true" />
```

but no success

Comment: Typos? -> layout-lagre-hdpi layout-lagre-mdpi layout-lagre-ldpi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if your API Level is already supporting this? I had this issue as well. In my case I used following line in the manifest, which set the TargetSDK to 4 (1.6), where the support of those different layouts started.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"  android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
```

Links:
[Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: HI Wolkenjaeger I have specified <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"  android:targetSdkVersion="7" /> no success.

Comment: I am not sure if you understood the concept of small, medium, large and hdpi, mdpi, ldpi.

Large is used for large screens like tablet devices and not high resolutions of mobile devices. Mobile devices are mostly medium screens.
What you are looking for is for medium screens (like the Samsung Galaxy) with high resolutions.
In this case you need to work with DPI. Layouts in android are automatically scaled to the correct size if you use DPI. However if you want to use different drawables, you must put them into drawables-hdpi -mdpi -ldpi 
I urge you to check out http://bit.ly/27nPxz again.

Answer (score 7):

I think the Problem is that people always create a large screen by AVD Manager and it sets the default density to 240 which is not supported by `/res/layout-large` 
If you want to want to test `/res/layout-large/any_layout.xml` then you should see the density of your virtual device it should be set to 160 not 240 or 120

Comment: Can you explain why density=160 for tablet? because I am facing problem

Comment: @RanjithKumar check this image: https://developer.android.com/images/screens_support/screens-ranges.png from this doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the set up emulator's default size is "large" and not "xlarge".

For example if the emulator size is "xlarge", then the "layout-large" folder will be ignored and the default "layout" folder will be used, because it can't find a "layout-xlarge" folder.

This is easy to identify if your using Android Studio.

Comment: How to identify this in Android Studio? I am facing the same problem - the layout is not used in Nexus 7 and 10 emulators - even though I have added **layout-large/activity_main.xml, layout-xlarge/activity_main.xml, layout-sw600dp/activity_main.xml, layout-sw720dp/activity_main.xml** and **layout-sw800dp/activity_main.xml**.

Comment: -> Open your AVD manager -> edit the AVD you're using -> At the hardware clone device, press "change" . You'll see that a size is displayed at the right. All the "phones" seem to be normal size, where if you choose from the "tablet" list the sizes would show large.