# Android muliple screen support?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to design an application which to support under three resolution. for that i use the code in manifest

and also create three folder layout , layout-large, layout-small for supporting three resolution, correspondingly i put the different resolution of image in drawable-hdpi ,drawable-ldpi ,drawable-mdpi , but whenever i run the app in different resolution it going to take low resolution image instead of different resolution i use.

I don`t know where i made the mistake, whether i have to add some code in layout xml or not. I also search the android developer forum and i do the application design as they insist.

Any one suggest some idea to achieve this.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you could check: have you set the minimum SDK version of your app to use version 4 (Android 1.6) support for this started?

Secondly, the *layout-large* and *layout-small* folders are designed for different *sized* screens (think tablet vs phone), and not resolution. If you're changing the resolution (DPI) of the device, you'll need to use *layout-hdpi*, *layout-ldpi* etc.

Further, if it's only the images you're changing, you should be placing the different images in *drawable-hdpi*, *drawable-ldpi* etc, and not *layout-xxxx*. If on a supported device, Android will pick the image from the correct folder, so you'll only have one layout folder (or 2 if you use *layout-land*)

Some (or all :S) of these points are covered in this link, to another question on StackOverflow. Try to use the search function before asking a question. Also, you'll find people are more receptive to providing answers to users with higher accept percentages.

[Android - layout-large folder is been ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438926/andriod-layout-large-folder-is-been-ignored)

Edit: for multiple screen support, also look at Fragments to better organise and fit your content for both large and small screen devices ([dev.Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), [worked example](http://portabledroid.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/programmatic-and-layout-fragments/))