# create app for multiple screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How can i create application design same for phone as well as tablet.As i have ldpi,mdpi and hdpi folder is there,my problem is somewhat like some phone has hdpi resolution while some tablet also has hdpi resolution ,in that how can one create same design for phone as well as tablet.

Thanks

Comment: A basic search on SO or Google would give a lot of examples. Plus, this question has been asked many times on SO too. Check this link for more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8428487/450534 or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309721/android-muliple-screen-support or even this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726764/android-layouts-for-multiple-screen-sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) page. You don't differentiate phone/tablet/etc screens based on the DPI value, you rather use the -small, -medium, -large, -xlarge, etc. tags.