# support for multiple resolution android

Tags: android

My app has 2 different resolution support, 480x800 and 320x240, i have created folder for them for instance layout-normal-hdpi and layout-normal-mdpi. But somehow emulotor is not picking up the ui for hdpi. I have created different layout aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

`layout-normal-mdpi` does not exist. Use `layout-mdpi` instead.

For reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

The Api level must also support this: [Android - layout-large folder is been ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438926/android-layout-large-folder-is-been-ignored)

Answer (score 8):

the way i am dealing with multiple screen is this way and its working fine.....if any one has improved wayso do guide me

**Screen size 480x800**

layout-normal-hdpi-480x800

drawable-normal-hdpi-480x800

**Screen size Galaxy Nexus---**
though its size is 1280x720 but in actual due to system bar its dimension(screen size) differs

layout-normal-xhdpi

drawable-normal-xhdpi

**Screen size Note 5.3---**

layout-normal-xhdpi-1280x800

drawable-normal-xhdpi-1280x800

**Screen size S3---**

layout-normal-xhdpi-1280x720

drawable-normal-xhdpi-1280x720

**Screen size  7inch tab 2 supporting OS version 3 and above---**
 dont write dimension 1026x600 bsz in actual due to system bar its dimension(screen size) differs

layout-large-mdpi

drawable-large-mdpi

**Screen size  7inch tab p1000 etc supoorting os verion less than 3---**

layout-large-hdpi-1024x600

drawable-large-hdpi-1024x600

**Screen size 1280x800 tab 10.1,10.2,note 10.1 etc---**
you can add dimension if you want other wise it is fine

layout-xlarge-mdpi

drawable-xlarge-mdpi

Answer (score 0):

Handling different resolutions can get tricky on Android.
The one true resource for this is the official site:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

It sounds to me like you might be confusing the size with the pixel intensity here.
Try to create the folders:
res/layout-sw480dp/main_activity.xml    //for the large screen
and
res/layout-sw320dp/main_activity.xml    //for the small one

Do you also have different drawable resource folders? Did you manage to get them to work?

Answer (score 0):

**Android Support Multiple Screeen**

**for tablet**

***Resolution 1280x800/1280x720***

values-sw720dp

drawable-sw720dp

layout-sw720dp

***Resolution 1024x600***

values-sw600dp

drawable-sw600dp

layout-sw600dp

***Resolution 480x800(twinner resolution, mdpi in tablet & hdpi in mobile)***

values-large-mdpi

drawable-large-mdpi

layout-large-mdpi(incase you want to make separate layout)

**for moblie**

***Resolution 1080x1920***

values-sw360dp-xxhdpi/values-sw360dp-notlong-xxhdpi (when 768x1280 is used)

drawable-xxhdpi/drawable-sw360dp-xxhdpi/drawable-sw360dp-notlong-xxhdpi(when 768x1280 is used)

layout-sw360dp

***Resolution 720x1280***
values-sw360dp-xhdpi

drawable-sw360dp-xhdpi

layout-sw360dp

***Resolution 768x1280***

values-sw360dp-notlong-xhdpi

drawable-sw360dp-notlong-xhdpi

layout-sw360dp

***Resolution 540x960***

values-sw360dp-hdpi

drawable-sw360dp-hdpi

layout-sw360dp

***Resolution 480x800***

values-hdpi

drawable-hdpi

layout-hdpi

***Resolution 320x480***

values-mdpi

drawable-mdpi

layout-mdpi

***Resolution 240x320***

values-ldpi

drawable-ldpi

layout-ldpi

**tags to add in manifest if your app needs to support full hd device only**

***for 1080x1920***

```
<screen
   android:screenDensity="480"
   android:screenSize="normal" />
```

Courtesy: [(Maulik Joshi)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346678/maulik-j)