# My Android app looks good on my emulator, looks aweful on my phone

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-xml, butterknife

I am currently working on an Alarm app for my phone. I started the app on my Genymotion emulator on my PC, and it looks like i want it too:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSRDB.jpg

However, when I start it on my phone via android studio it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e59lj.jpg

When I wrote my xml code, i made sure to use things like dip, and dp. Not once do I ever use exact dimensions when placing things. I believe I scaled my image buttons a smidgen. I also scaled the clock at the top center in the Y direction only. Any thoughts or Ideas on why this might be happening? I am starting to get the feeling than an emulator should just be used for functionality testing only, and not UI/UX design.

I have a suspicion it might have something to do with some of my dependencies(ButterKnife for example). I keep getting these in my console:

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23$1>
```

and this:

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor>
```

Anywho, any thoughts or input would be very much appreciated.

Comment: On which device are you testing ?

Comment: An HTC ONE, model number is: HTC PN072

Comment: Are you sure you are testing on same model in emulator and real one both ?

Comment: I am definitely testing on a different device in my Emulator. I am testing on a Genymotion Custom phone: 768X1280, with 160dpi. I focused more on the 160dpi then the dimensions.  However, it was my understanding that that didn't necessarily matter because of the way DPI and DP are. Am I wrong in assuming that?

Comment: "I focused more on the 160dpi then the dimensions." What does this even mean? Show us your drawables for each density folder you have. And don't worry about ButterKnife, that's not it. Also, tell us how many sp are you using for each text view.

Comment: Dimensions in pixels: 768x1280,
Dots per Inch: 160. 

Dip and Dp are scalable. So if use dp as the dimension in all of my text sizes, layout containers, ect, then I won't have two worry about weather the device is infinity x infinity, or just small x small. Am I wrong in assuming that? I asked that same question in my previous answer to Shree Krishna. 

The only drawables I have are the clock images below the current time text. I only have a single drawable folder with those two images. They are 48x48 pixels large. In fact, they weren't quite big enough for my liking, so i scaled them up.

Comment: Do you have all your resources in different densities? You can read more about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515977/support-for-multiple-resolution-android

Comment: Thank you  jakubbialkowski for you comment, that def. pointed me in the right direction. My issues was that it looked fantastic on my Tablet, on the emulator, but horrible on my phone. I added a values-normal and a values-large folder and that fixed the issue for me on my phone, whilst not changing it on my tablets. So yea, thank you.