# Android options menu title cutoff

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-menu

I have a simple options menu with just titles defined, no icons and the text is getting chopped off:
[image: Nexus 7 options menu cut off]

What can I do to avoid this? I'm on Jelly Bean 4.2 and testing on a Nexus 7. I can't find anything on alignment or menu positioning in the docs or through Google.

The XML for the menu definition is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_create_user"
        android:title="Create">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
        android:title="Refresh">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_remote"
        android:title="View Remote">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Any thoughts or ideas?

*EDIT*
Looking further, it appears apart of my problem is that it looks like it's displaying this at 'phone size' and not 'tablet' size. Comparing the size of my action bar to say, that of Google Maps or Drive it's a lot larger, and more pixelated (see fuzyness on menu icon?)

So I guess part of the problem is how do I tell my app I'm on a tablet? I'm using the standard Theme.Holo.* in the application config, but thats the only L&F I have setup.

Comment: This is more like a device/ROM issue than an app issue. You can, however add them to the action bar if you wanted to (add android:showAsAction=always to the menu items)

Comment: It does it on both in an Emulator and the Device (bone stock Nexus 7). Even if I put them in the action bar the characters still get chooped off, even with one item in the list.

Comment: That's a bit odd. If you can create a sample project that reproduces this error, post it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, just found the issue and posted the answer. Essentially it's phone vs tablet layout and needing some 'magical' entry in the manifest to make it act like one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it was a layout issue, but it's not really obvious. All I had to do to 'fix' this was add:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"  android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

to my manifest file. I think **minSdkVersion** can be anything higher then 3 where apparently different screen size support was added. I'm guessing phone layouts simply don't have room for the text view in the action bar.

Discovered this from another StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438926/android-layout-large-folder-is-been-ignored). Up to this point I had not read anything for what needs to be done for different screen sizes and the differences between tables and phones.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problems with this simple line in the manifest

`supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"`